# R Factorial Design AOV, ANOVA Wrong Degrees of Freedom for Interaction

Tags: r, statistics

I am running the following R code and getting 3 degrees of freedom for the A:C interaction. However Design Expert and other software give 1 degree of freedom for the interaction.

The rule is the DoF of factor 1 times the DoF in factor 2 give the degrees of freedom in their interaction.

```
A=rep(c(-1,1),4)
B=rep(c(-1,-1,1,1),2)
C=c(rep(-1,4),rep(1,4))
D=A*B*C
E=A*B
cbind(A,B,C,D,E)
treatments<-c("e","ad","bd","abe","cde","ac","bc","abcde")
dat<-data.frame(
    A=A,B=B,C=C,D=D,E=E,
    response=c(
    8,10,32,52,15,20,40,63
    )
)
```

[image: Normal Probability Plot of Effects]

```
dat1<-dat
dat1[,1:5]<-lapply(dat1[,1:5],factor)
str(dat1)
    'data.frame':   8 obs. of  6 variables:
     $ A       : Factor w/ 2 levels "-1","1": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
     $ B       : Factor w/ 2 levels "-1","1": 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2
     $ C       : Factor w/ 2 levels "-1","1": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
     $ D       : Factor w/ 2 levels "-1","1": 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 2
     $ E       : Factor w/ 2 levels "-1","1": 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2
     $ response: num  8 10 32 52 15 20 40 63
amod<-aov(response~B+D+E+A:C,data=dat1)
summary(amod)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)   
B            1 2244.5  2244.5  4489.0 0.0095 **
D            1    0.0     0.0     0.0 1.0000   
E            1  162.0   162.0   324.0 0.0353 * 
A:C          3  479.0   159.7   319.3 0.0411 * 
Residuals    1    0.5     0.5                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Even though this is a fractional factorial experiment specifically a 2^(5-2) or quarter fraction of five factors the DoF should be 1 for A:C for any factorial design.

I'm posting here because this is a program issue, r, specifically and not a statistics question.

This is true for the anova function running a lm model as well.

Comment: I *think* R is doing the combinations of low A low C, low A high C, high A low C, high A high C. Can we tell R not to do that? This would be 4 levels, giving a DoF of 3.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want, but `I(A*C)` might do what you want?